# Unable to run PDAL in stream mode with PCD input

Tags: pdal, pcd, pcl

I'm trying to run PDAL pipeline over point cloud in PCD format with custom dimension.

Dimension is 4-bytes float, and it's recognizable by pdal info, CloudCompare opens it correctly as well.

The problem is I can't run any PDAL applications in stream-mode which leads to loading thw whole 10GB cloud into memory.

Specifying `--stream` flag fails with error:
`PDAL: Couldn't run pipeline in requested execution mode.`

```
(pdalenv) user@user-nix:~/wherever$ pdal pipeline --validate ./pipeline.json 
{
    "error_detail": "",
    "streamable": false,
    "valid": true
}
```

Pipeline:

```
{
    "pipeline": [
        "./cloud.pcd",
        {
            "type": "filters.crop",
            "polygon": "POLYGON((544.470884390047 186.546522505681,464.354502764788 188.636833844229,464.127438662174 100.368684748664,537.490578240213 100.606814054121,544.470884390047 186.546522505681))"
        },
        "./cloud_cropped.pcd"
    ]
}
```

PCD header:

```
# .PCD v0.7 - Point Cloud Data file format
VERSION 0.7
FIELDS x y z intensity custom
SIZE 4 4 4 4 4
TYPE F F F F F
COUNT 1 1 1 1 1
WIDTH 501382183
HEIGHT 1
VIEWPOINT 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
POINTS 501382183
DATA binary
```